# Move an array element from a position to another with condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-manipulation

i 'm looking for a quick and robust way to move an element of an array to the top of the stack. My case is:
I have an array of objects like this:

```
array = [{label: yu, value: uy}, {label: EUR, value: EUR}, {label: CY, value: CY}].
```

I want to move the element with value EUR to the top of the array so as to be the first element. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`Array#sort()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjtnMuo06HUAhXJo48KHZFpCagQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsort&usg=AFQjCNEGi0Cab6xU1_1jrxG44Qu1jxuBXg&sig2=ESkxupeVm8YRHFYDmA0Mwg) compare the value matching with `EUR` .its matching set with first place with in a array

```js
var array = [{ label: 'yu', value: 'uy'},  { label: 'EUR', value: 'EUR'  },{ label: 'CY', value: 'CY' }]

console.log(array.sort((a, b) => a.value == 'EUR' ? -1 : b.value == 'EUR' ? 1 : 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr= [{label: "yu", value:" uy"}, {label:"EUR", value:"EUR"}, {label: "CY", value: "CY"}];



  arr.splice(0,0,arr.splice(arr.findIndex(el=>el.label==="EUR"),1));

console.log(arr);
```

Splice removes / pushes elements out of/ into an array.

```
arr.splice(0,0,el);
```

Add el into the first position.

```
arr.splice(i,1);
```

Remove the element at i.

```
arr.findIndex(el=>el.label===" EUR");
```

Find the index of the first element with the label EUR.

Answer (score 1):

please see following fiddle.

1. identify index of that element you want to move.
2. just remove that element and unshift the array.

   `array.unshift(array.splice(index,1)[0]);`

   [Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/milindpatel/6hsfjv73/2/)

Answer (score 1):

While you like to sort the array, I suggest to use the delta of the comparison directly without using a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). The advantage of this solution is, it works for more than one object in the array. All items with the same key/value pair are sorted to top.

```js
const toTop = (key, value) => (a, b) => (b[key] === value) - (a[key] === value);
let array = [{ label: 'yu', value: 'uy' }, { label: 'EUR', value: 'EUR' }, { label: 'CY', value: 'CY' }];

array.sort(toTop('value', 'EUR'));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hello, Here instead of passing one value like 'EUR' , If I want to pass array of values say ['EUR', 'CY'] and here object need to sort based on array of values..in this case what is the approach..

Comment: @Roy, you could get the index first and sort by this value or if not exists, take a large value to sort all other items to the end of the array.